# Form submitting with GET method and location.hash value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Have an html form with method="get", no action & button with type="submit"

```js
    (function(){
        jQuery(".time").text(Date.now());
    })();
    jQuery(".set-hash").on("click", function () {
        location.hash = "hash";
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
    <div class="time"></div>
    <input type="text" name="param">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="set-hash">Set Hash</button>
</form>
```

Case 1.

- Click Submit button.

See the request is sent.

Case 2.

- Click Set Hash button
- Click Submit button

See the request isn't sent. Nothing changed.

Case 3.

- Click Set Hash button
- Set any value to Param input
- Click Submit button
- Set any other value to Param input
- Click Submit button

See that the request is sent only when param changes.

So the question is: **why the request is sent only when param changes?**

P. S.

When change method from GET to POST everything works fine. But I need the request parameters in the address bar.

Comment: Try to put an action other than `""` to your form.

Comment: Tried, didn't help. Looks it's something with location.hash

Answer (score 0):

Its working here try this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Doc title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
        jQuery(".time").text(Date.now());
        var url = window.location.href;
        jQuery(".url").text(url);
        jQuery(".set-hash").on("click", function () {
                  location.hash = "hash";
                 // alert("test");
        });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
    <div class="time"></div>
    <input type="text" name="param">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="set-hash">Set Hash</button><br />
    Current URL:<div class="url"></div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference? I see only .url manipulation added.

Comment: Check your script. I think, the brackets are not in proper order. Your function used to get terminated after calling date()

Comment: Checked, doesn't work :( When Hash is set - time doesn't change

Comment: Have u kept both date and click func inside ready function? It should work.

Comment: Yes, both functions are inside ready function. Chrome last + win7, Firefox last + win7, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the reason yet.

Seems the trouble is connected with anchors that browsers handle some special way. When I change location.host browser tries to jump to the anchor added. And somehow this affects submit button handling.

Had to use workaround - to storage the data from the hash in the localStorage.